# Regular expresion - how to find IP in string that also contains numbers with more dots

Tags: regex

Im trying to match IP from a string that might contains also numbers with more dots (e.g. 1.2.3.4.5.6.7)

If I use the symbol x insted of dot, the Regex works fine:

```
RexEx: .*\b(0x0x0x0)\b.*

String: 0x0x0x0x0x0 ff 0x0x0x0 yy 0x0x0x0x0x0

Result: 0x0x0x0x0x0 ff **0x0x0x0** yy 0x0x0x0x0x0
```

but when I look for IP(with dot):

```
RegEx:  .*\b(0\.0\.0\.0)\b.*

String:  0.0.0.0.0.0 ff 0.0.0.0 yy 0.0.0.0.0.0

Result: 0.0.0.0.0.0 ff 0.0.0.0 yy 0.0.**0.0.0.0**
```

I receive the tail of the last doted number

How can I use dot to retrieve the IP?

Comment: Why `.*` around the pattern? Are you trying to extract the last occurrence? What is the regex library? In general, it is achieved with lookarounds, `\b(?<!0\.)0\.0\.0\.0\b(?!\.0)`, see [demo](https://regex101.com/r/16ie0R/1)

Comment: Wiktor Stribiżew, also without the .*. I tried it in the https://regex101.com/ tool

Comment: But https://regex101.com/r/16ie0R/1 might not work for you in the end anyway. What are you doing and where?

Comment: So you do not want to match at the end of the string? Why? What are the requirements?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To look for four dot-separated digits not surrounded by more dot-separated digits ... say what you are looking for.

```
(?<!\d\.)(?<!\d)\d+(\.\d+){3}(?!\.?\d)
```

The two lookbehinds is because most PCRE-compatible engines do not permit a variable-length lookbehind (so you can't say `(?<!\d\.?)`).  So we explicitly say that the string before the match can't match `\d\.` and also not `\d`.  The lookahead after the match covers both cases nicely with an optional dot.

Demo: https://regex101.com/r/YMmdtT/1

Answer (score 1):

That's because a dot is not a word character and x is, so `\b` won't quite cut it for you with dots. You might want to replace `\b` with something like `[^.]` ([see this demo](https://regex101.com/r/s9RkIu/3/)) or just replace dots with x-es before you run your regex.

Comment: Your solution is wrong because it does not allow a match at the end of the string.

Comment: Updated, now it matches the end of string also

Comment: But not the start of string.